# Zoom in/out scene with SDL2

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I'm pretty new to SDL2 and I'm working on a small 2D game in C++. I'm trying to figure out how to do some simple operations with this library, mainly because I'd like to learn something new from this experience.

I've a bunch of elements, some of which are renderable items that are part of a scene, while some others are HUD items. The problem I'm facing with is that I want to zoom in and out the scene without affecting the HUD elements.
This is how I approached it:

- I created a default window and renderer with `SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer`.
- I created a texture out of the renderer with `SDL_CreateTexture` and set the texture access pattern to `SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET`.
- Initially I copied all scene entities through the renderer to the targeted texture, that is I set the rendering context to the targeted texture using `SDL_SetRenderTarget` before to copy textures over.
- I set back the renderer to the default context and copied the targeted texture using `SDL_RenderCopy`.
- Finally I copied all HUD entities to the renderer (that is, directly to the default context).

So far so good, everything works as expected and I can easily zoom in and out the scene by using the right source and destination rectangles when copying the targeted texture over to the renderer through `SDL_RenderCopy`.

My question is: is this a sensible approach or is there a much better solution to do that?
It works just fine, that's good, but it looks to me a bit tricky and I'm not completely convinced of that.

Comment: Is there a problem rendering in two steps? The "scene" with the set of "scene" transformations then the HUD with the "HUD" transformations? I've not used SDL for more then creating an opengl context in the past, so YMMV on this.

Comment: @Aumnayan As long as the rendering context is the same, I cannot see how two steps would solve the issue. As mentioned I have the problem that I want to zoom the scene without affecting HUD elements (that is, they must keep their original sizes). Create two different rendering contexts is the only solution that came up to my mind.

Comment: @skypjack as far as I remember you can scale rendered textures by changing destination rectangle size. That way you wouldn't need extra render to texture.

Comment: @keltar Yeah, I usually did it with a single texture. Anyway, to zoom a scene in a 2D game would mean to properly change scales and positions of each texture and it ends up with visual errors because of number approximations. That's why I used a targeted texture and scaled it. I draw the whole scene in its logical size, then I zoom it as a whole. Does it make sense?

Comment: @skypjack yes if zomming transition is animated that's probably a way to go. Shouldn't be too expensive either. However I don't think there should be any noticeable rounding errors even with animated zooming.

Comment: @keltar Yeah, animated zooming. Sorry, I forgot to mention it. I tried doing it by modifying positions and scales, but I got a terrible result (probably an error my side?) and a lot of math and operations, while this way is straightforward. Anyway, what's the way to go? Using a targeted texture?

Comment: @skypjack either what you've already have or scale individual elements, I don't know any other option. I personally prefer second one as it should give sharper edges and potentially allows you to skip rendering elements that are outside of scaled view. But if render to texture solves your problem - it is completely fine. Even better, you can change it later at any time (e.g. if at some point you'll want some extreme levels of scaling when render texture resolution becomes a problem).

Comment: @keltar Good point. It's worth it to put the comment in a more detailed answer and I'll be glad to vote up it, if you want. ;-)